# How can I manage a WebSocket in a CI/CD deployed app on AWS, Where would be the most logical place to create a gateway with WebSocket in this context?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, websocket, nestjs, aws-api-gateway

I'm currently developing an application using a stack that includes NestJS, PostgreSQL, and AWS. The application will feature a chat environment that utilizes the OpenAI API and WebSocket for real-time communication.

- How can I effectively manage WebSocket in an application that is deployed on AWS using CI/CD practices?
- Are there any recommended tools or services that I should use for this purpose?
- Are there specific considerations or best practices when it comes to transitioning a WebSocket from a local environment to AWS?
- If I want to leverage the AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda in this scenario, how can I best incorporate them into my application?
- Are there potential challenges I might face during this process and what are the possible solutions or workarounds?
- Where would be the most logical place to create a gateway with WebSocket in this context?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I effectively manage WebSocket in an application that is deployed on AWS using CI/CD practices?

What does manage mean here? Keep updated? State management?

> Are there any recommended tools or services that I should use for this purpose?

IaC is the easiest way to manage resources. An IaC template that defines an AWS API, the database (aurora for example) and related permissions and resources can go into a Git repository and manage the infrastructure resources to appropriately match code versions.

> Are there specific considerations or best practices when it comes to transitioning a WebSocket from a local environment to AWS?

If you can map it to a swagger template it can simplify the conversion. Or if it is defined locally via code.

> If I want to leverage the AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda in this scenario, how can I best incorporate them into my application?

API Gateway will use Lambda to process each request. Responses to out via web sockets. You might also look at appsync.

> Are there potential challenges I might face during this process and what are the possible solutions or workarounds?

Many. This where discovery of requirements pitfalls and optimizations comes into play. there are many paths forward but it all depends on the restrictions of the workflow.

> Where would be the most logical place to create a gateway with WebSocket in this context?

Either on the front end (internet can access) or internally. But it depends on who is connecting and to what.